# Akka - AbstractBehaviorWithStash?

Tags: java, akka, akka-typed

is there a way to start out an Akka Typed `Behavior` with a stash in **Java**? The reason is simple, during the first stage, the `Behavior` waits for a certain kind of message, initializes itself with it and should `stash()` every other message until it got that message, then `unstash()` them and proceed as normal.

With functional, this is easily doable, sure, but is there a way to do so with `AbstractBehavior` and it's `createReceive()` method, because that one doesn't allow me to return a stashed `Behavior` via `Behaviors.withStash( stash -> ...)`, since it expects a `Receive` ?

Answer (score 2):

In the OO API, I would expect that the approach would be to inject the stash through constructor args from a static `create` method.

```java
// Apologies if this Java is atrocious
public class ActorWithAStash extends AbstractBehavior<ActorWithAStash.Command> {
  public static Behavior<Command> create() {
    Behaviors.setup(context ->
      Behaviors.withStash(100, stash ->
        new ActorWithAStash(context, stash)
      )
    );
  }

  public interface Command;

  private ActorWithAStash(ActorContext<Command> context, StashBuffer<Command> stash) {
    this.context = context;
    this.stash = stash;
  }

  private ActorContext<Command> context;
  private StashBuffer<Command> stash;
}
```